# Passing Value from Uitextfiled to selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have UITextField's name _nameField
I want to passing _nameField.text by using @Selector() to

```
 -(void)userSetStats:(NSString *)name{
```

This is my Uitextfield

```
_nameField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.height/2-100, self.view.frame.size.width/2-20, 200, 40)];
_nameField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_nameField];
```

This is my button

```
UIButton *confirm = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.height/2-50, self.view.frame.size.width/2+60, 100, 40)];
[confirm setTitle:@"Confirm" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[confirm addTarget:self action:@selector(userSetStats:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:confirm];
```

and this is my userSetStats:

```
-(void)userSetStats:(NSString *)name{
NSMutableDictionary *userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[userData setObject:name forKey:@"Name"];
```

For now i can send value but the value i get is

```
Name = "<UIButton: 0x9a2ddd0; frame = (190 220; 100 40); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9a2df00>>";
```

I try to find any answer in this website I found some of it but i do not understand it.

Comment: That error message is incomplete.  Please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addTarget's selector can be only the sender. In this case you don't need the parameter.

```
[confirm addTarget:self action:@selector(userSetStats) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the selector is...

```
-(void)userSetStats
{
    NSMutableDictionary *userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [userData setObject:_nameField.text forKey:@"Name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Action methods in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) have the following forms:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Where `sender` is the control that triggered the action.  Therefore:

```
-(void)userSetStats:(id)sender {

    NSMutableDictionary *userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

If you want the title from the (sending) button, then:

```
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [userData setObject:button.title forKey:@"Name"];
```

else if you want the text from the text field then:

```
    [userData setObject:_nameField.text forKey:@"Name"];
```